# Prove that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{(\sin^n{2x} - \cos^n{x})}\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've calculated the integral when $n$ is $1,2,3$ with a calculator. But I can't prove that:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{(\sin^n{2x} - \cos^n{x})}\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$$
If it's true, how to prove this? And if it's false, why?

Comment: We can use Wallis integral formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true. We have that for $t=\pi/2-2x$,
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n(2x)dx
=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x\right)dx
=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(t)dt.$$

Comment: how do you explain the last equality?

Comment: $\cos x$ is an even function ($f(x)=f(-x)$)

Comment: @egreg now, it makes sense!

Comment: @egreg why delete the edit?

Comment: @vidyarthi There's also a flip of the bounds, now I see it clearly and will reinstate the edit.

Comment: @egreg now, again, it really makes sense. Well, silly mistakes passby unnoticed, isnt it?